# "Invalid operation: Not authorized to get credentials of role" trying to load json from S3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I always get the error

```
Invalid operation: Not authorized to get credentials of role arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/default_glue_role
```

I simply want to load from a json from S3 into a Redshift cluster. It is not clear to me what role I have to attach (to Redshift ?).

I have tried attaching the following IAM policy to Redshift

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxx:role/default_glue_role"
    }
}
```

and also tried with `"Resource": "*"` but I always get same error.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Look at the "trust relationships" for the role in the IAM Console. It should say "redshift.amazonaws.com". If it doesn't, fix that. If it does, then run `aws iam get-role --role-name ROLE_NAME` from the command-line and paste update your question with the output.

Comment: Also, read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-access-permissions.html and ensure that you're granting the right permissions. Don't try to share a role between Redshift and Glue.

Comment: @Parsifal You solved my issue, too. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same error but in Redshift serverless instead of regular cluster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77390866/8529250

Answer (score 1):

I had a long chat with AWS support about this same issues. A few things to check:

1. Your s3 bucket region is the same as your redshift cluster region
2. You are not signed in as the root aws user, you need to create a user with the correct permissions and sign in as this user to run your queries
3. You should add the following permissions to your user and redshift policies:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*",
                "redshift:*",
                "sqlworkbench:*",
                "sts:*",
                "secretsmanager:*",
                "s3-object-lambda:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "sns:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "tag:*",
                "redshift-data:*",
                "sqlworkbench:*",
                "redshift-serverless:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. You should have the following trust relationships in your redshift and user role:

```html
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "s3.amazonaws.com",
                    "redshift.amazonaws.com",
                    "iam.amazonaws.com",
                    "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The actual set of permissions you need might be less but this is what worked for me. Took me a long time to figure this out! I hope it helps.

**It looks like you might also need to add permissions for glue.**

The redshift-serverless permission might tell you it's causing an error but you should be able to save it anyway (AWS told me to do this)

Answer (score 1):

For everyone using Terraform:

What fixed for me it was the (4) suggestion from @patrick-ward:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dms_assume_role" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      identifiers = [
        "s3.amazonaws.com",
        "redshift.amazonaws.com",
        "iam.amazonaws.com",
        "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com",
        "dms.amazonaws.com"
      ]
      type = "Service"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "dms-access-for-endpoint" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dms_assume_role.json
  name               = "dms-access-for-endpoint"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "dms-access-for-endpoint-AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role"
  role       = aws_iam_role.dms-access-for-endpoint.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "dms-cloudwatch-logs-role" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dms_assume_role.json
  name               = "dms-cloudwatch-logs-role"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "dms-cloudwatch-logs-role-AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSCloudWatchLogsRole"
  role       = aws_iam_role.dms-cloudwatch-logs-role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "dms-vpc-role" {
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dms_assume_role.json
  name               = "dms-vpc-role"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "dms-vpc-role-AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonDMSVPCManagementRole"
  role       = aws_iam_role.dms-vpc-role.name
}
```